# autocomplete in zsh after `npm run tdd` command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm using OS X 10.10.3, I have installed `zsh`. And every time when I want to run a specific test I configured in `package.json` to execute `npm run tdd` followed by the test file.

In linux systems if I press tab after this command:

`npm run tdd ~/`

will show me the folders or will attempt to autocomplete the instruction, however this doesn't happen in `zsh` on OS X, it just makes the noise like there are no recommendations for this.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: There's a closed ticket on zsh about this -> https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/6897 - it seems it's unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your .zshrc:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

that should get you going. Now, read

```
man zshcompsys
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(, reading zshcompsys though.

Comment: sorry, could not find anything that help with this :(

Comment: @Nico From `man zshcompsys`: "If the system was installed completely, it should be enough to call the shell function `compinit` from your initialization file;".

Comment: Calling compinit doesn't fix de issue